# Trying to fetch records from the Mongodb based on criteria which is consuming so much of time

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```
public Object getSearchCriteria(@RequestParam(value = "id") String userId,

 @RequestParam(value = "identifier", required = false) String policyIdentifier

Query searchQuery = new Query();

if (identifier != null && !identifier.isEmpty())
   searchQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("PolicyID").is(identifier);
   if (business != null && !business.isEmpty())
        searchQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("Business").is(business));
    List<policy> policy= mongoOps.find(searchQuery, Policy.class);
     return policy;
}
```

Comment: Definitely it will take some time. To reduce the time better go for pagination design.
Because if data grows then to fetching 7000 records it will take more time.
Try to have a page limit lesser than 50. If needed give the next 50 records. 
Dont throw all records at once.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion . I need fetch the data of 1000 records on index based .Can you please suggest